# Why don't this return the "mrcf" value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
m = int(input('Enter value of m : \t'))
n = int(input('Enter the value of n : \t'))
def GCD(m, n):
 for i in range(1,min(m,n)+1):
  if (m % i) == 0  and (n % i) == 0:
    mrcf = i
  return (mrcf)
```

**This isn't returning anything. Why?** -  btb. I just started Py, and I'm already lovin this language :)

Comment: you have indentation problem sir

Comment: Why do you need the extra variable? Why not just `return i`?

Comment: You really want to use more than one space per indentation level. The [Python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) tells you to use 4 spaces, and with good reason. Your `return` statement is inside the `for` loop, and should not be, but with just one space difference that is very hard to spot.

Comment: You don't call the function `GCD`; you only define the function.

Comment: Barmar, why have you left my comment -1? bad practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the intent of this function GCD, you're potentially updating mrcf multiple times, not just returning the first occurence of `(m % i) == 0 and (n % i) == 0`:

```
m = int(input('Enter value of m : \t'))
n = int(input('Enter the value of n : \t'))

def GCD(m, n):
  for i in range(min(m,n), 1, -1):
    if (m % i) == 0  and (n % i) == 0:
      return i
  return 1

print(GCD(m, n))
```

UPDATE: as @Barmar suggested, reversing the loop is more efficient

Comment: Alternatively, you can reverse the order of the loop and then return the first one that's found.